# Optimize a list function that creates too much garbage (not stack overflow)

Tags: performance, list, haskell, garbage-collection, automatic-differentiation

I have that Haskell function, that's causing more than 50% of all the allocations of my program, causing 60% of my run time to be taken by the GC. I run with a small stack (`-K10K`) so there is no stack overflow, but can I make this function faster, with less allocation?

The goal here is to calculate the product of a matrix by a vector. I cannot use [`hmatrix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) for example because this is part of a bigger function using the [`ad` Automatic Differentiation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad) package, so I need to use lists of `Num`. At runtime I suppose the use of the `Numeric.AD` module means my types must be `Scalar Double`.

```
listMProd :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
listMProd mdt vdt = go mdt vdt 0
  where
    go [] _  s = [s]
    go ls [] s = s : go ls vdt 0
    go (y:ys) (x:xs) ix = go ys xs (y*x+ix)
```

Basically we loop through the matrix, multiplying and adding an accumulator until we reach the end of the vector, storing the result, then continuing restarting the vector again. I have a `quickcheck` test verifying that I get the same result than the matrix/vector product in hmatrix.

I have tried with `foldl`, `foldr`, etc. Nothing I've tried makes the function faster (and some things like `foldr` cause a space leak).

Running with profiling tells me, on top of the fact that this function is where most of the time and allocation is spent, that there are loads of [`Cells`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad-4.2.4/docs/Numeric-AD-Internal-Reverse.html#t:Cells) being created, `Cells` being a data type from the `ad` package.

A simple test to run:

```
import Numeric.AD

main = do
    let m :: [Double] = replicate 400 0.2
        v :: [Double] = replicate 4 0.1
        mycost v m = sum $ listMProd m v 
        mygrads = gradientDescent (mycost (map auto v)) (map auto m)
    print $ mygrads !! 1000
```

This on my machine tells me GC is busy 47% of the time.

Any ideas?

Comment: More info!  How are you running this program?  Where is your test harness?  What concrete types are you using?  What are the flags and version on your Haskell compiler?

Comment: Added some info. That function is called via the ad grad function which uses its own types (instances of Num). Profiling shows allocations of "Cells".

Comment: Some half-informed suggestions: did you consider using mutable state with `ST`? And [stream-fusion](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stream-fusion-0.1.2.5/docs/Data-List-Stream.html)/[conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit)/[pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes)? Maybe (?) it could even be worthwhile to transform your vector-list into something else, e.g. an [unboxed vector](http://lambda.jstolarek.com/2013/04/haskell-as-fast-as-c-a-case-study/)? I do not have experience with any of these techniques but maybe the links can help you further.

Comment: Just to exclude an obvious thing: what if you add a bang pattern in the last clause of `go`, e.g. `go (y:ys) (x:xs) !ix = go ys xs (y*x+ix)`

Comment: I'm starting to think this is linked to AD itself and not my code. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888615/how-to-get-more-performance-out-of-automatic-differentiation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072218/how-to-do-automatic-differentiation-on-hmatrix

Comment: Could you give a minimum executable example?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, run example added

Answer (score 7):

A very simple optimization is to make the `go` function strict by its accumulator parameter, because it's small, can be unboxed if `a` is primitive and always needs to be fully evaluated:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
listMProd :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
listMProd mdt vdt = go mdt vdt 0
  where
    go [] _  !s = [s]
    go ls [] !s = s : go ls vdt 0
    go (y:ys) (x:xs) !ix = go ys xs (y*x+ix)
```

On my machine, it gives 3-4x speedup (compiled with `-O2`).

On the other hand, intermediate lists shouldn't be strict so they could be fused.

Comment: Mhh, good idea, but it doesn't help at all in my use case (no improvement in speed or GC usage). I think the fact that the function is called via the ad library is what's impacting the performance (I see a Cells datatype with a strict Int field).