# Numeric.AD - type variable escaping its scope

Tags: haskell, automatic-differentiation

I'm trying to use [automatic differentiation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad-4.2.4/docs/Numeric-AD.html) in Haskell for a nonlinear control problem, but have some problems getting it to work. I basically have a `cost` function, which should be optimized given an initial state. The types are:

```
data Reference a = Reference a deriving Functor
data Plant a = Plant a deriving Functor

optimize :: (RealFloat a) => Reference a -> Plant a -> [a] -> [[a]]
optimize ref plant initialInputs = gradientDescent (cost ref plant) initialInputs

cost :: (RealFloat a) => Reference a -> Plant a -> [a] -> a
cost = ...
```

This results in the following error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Reference
                                (Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a)'
            with actual type `t'
  because type variable `s' would escape its scope
This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
  a type expected by the context:
    Data.Reflection.Reifies s Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Tape =>
    [Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a]
    -> Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a
  at test.hs:13:5-50
Relevant bindings include
  initialInputs :: [a] (bound at test.hs:12:20)
  ref :: t (bound at test.hs:12:10)
  optimize :: t -> t1 -> [a] -> [[a]] (bound at test.hs:12:1)
In the first argument of `cost', namely `ref'
In the first argument of `gradientDescent', namely
  `(cost ref plant)'
```

I'm not even sure if I understand the error correctly. Is it, that the types of `ref` and `plant` need access to the `s`, which is inside the scope of the first argument to `gradientDescent`?

Is it possible to make this work? While looking for a solution, I tried reducing the problem to a minimal example and found that the following definition produces a similar error message:

```
optimize f inputs = gradientDescent f inputs
```

This seems odd, because `optimize = gradientDescent` doesn't produce any error.

Comment: What are `Reference` and `Plant`?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/29393417/414413, both questions are about the type of the first argument to `gradientDescent`, with essentially the same answer but different errors prompting the question.

Comment: `Reference` and `Plant` are Functors. More specifically, `Reference` is a simple algebraic datatype and `Plant` is type alias for a `Wire` from the `netwire` library.

Comment: `optimize = gradientDescent` works because unapplied this can and will infer a rank-n type. When you expand it like that the rank-n type has to be specified as it is beyond what any type system can infer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cost ref plant` has the type `[a] -> a` where `a` is the same `a` as in the signature to `optimize`

```
optimize :: (RealFloat a) => Reference a -> Plant a -> [a] -> [[a]]
                                       ^          ^
                                       |          ------------
                                       ------------------v   v
optimize ref plant initialInputs = gradientDescent (cost ref plant) initialInputs
                                                         ^   ^
                                   -----------------------   |
                                   v          v---------------
cost :: (RealFloat a) => Reference a -> Plant a -> [a] -> a
cost = ...
```

But the type of [`gradientDescent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad-4.2.4/docs/Numeric-AD.html#v:gradientDescent) is

```
gradientDescent :: (Traversable f, Fractional a, Ord a) =>
                   (forall s. Reifies s Tape => f (Reverse s a) -> Reverse s a) -> 
                   f a -> [f a]
```

The first argument to `gradientDescent` needs to be able to take (for *any* `s`) `[Reverse s a]` and return a `Reverse s a`, but `cost ref plant` can only take `[a]` an return an `a`.

Since `Reference` and `Plant` are both `Functor`s, you can convert `ref` and `plant` from `Reference a` and `Plant a` to `Reference (Reverse s a)` and `Plant (Reverse s a)` by `fmap`ing [`auto`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad-4.2.4/docs/Numeric-AD.html#v:auto).

```
optimize :: (RealFloat a) => Reference a -> Plant a -> [a] -> [[a]]
optimize ref plant initialInputs = gradientDescent (cost (fmap auto ref) (fmap auto plant)) initialInputs
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work now, though it is quite ugly. For some reason, `fmap`ing `auto` doesn't work and I have to use `realToFrac` instead. I also have to `fmap` twice over both arguments. Also `Plant a` being an alias for a `Wire s e m a a` from `netwire` complicates things. I'll test my solution now and post the answer, if it works.

Comment: If `Plant a` is an alias `Wire s e m a a` then `Plant` isn't a `Functor`.

What do you mean by having to `fmap` twice over both arguments?