# Automatic differentiation with custom data types

Tags: haskell, automatic-differentiation

I'm facing a problem while trying to differentiate custom data types using the Haskell [ad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad) library. There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391114/how-to-do-automatic-differentiation-on-complex-datatypes), which has been helpful, but I feel might be unsufficient in this case.

Here is a simplified version of the issue that I'm facing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}

import Numeric.AD
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Traversable

data Sample a = Sample a deriving (Show, Traversable, Foldable, Functor)

data Model s a = Model {
  sample_logp :: s -> a
}

instance Functor (Model s) where
  fmap f m = Model {
    sample_logp = f . (sample_logp m)
  }

dtest :: (Num a) => Model (Sample a) a -> Sample a -> Sample a
dtest m x = grad (\x' -> test (fmap auto m) x') x

test :: Num a => Model (Sample a) a -> Sample a -> a
test m x = (sample_logp m)  x
```

This results in the following error message:

```
Test.hs:22:42:
Could not deduce (a ~ Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a)
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the type signature for
             dtest :: Num a => Model (Sample a) a -> Sample a -> Sample a
  at Test.hs:21:10-62
or from (Data.Reflection.Reifies
           s Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Tape)
  bound by a type expected by the context:
             Data.Reflection.Reifies s Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Tape =>
             Sample (Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a)
             -> Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a
  at Test.hs:22:13-49
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        dtest :: Num a => Model (Sample a) a -> Sample a -> Sample a
      at Test.hs:21:10
Expected type: Model
                 (Sample (Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a)) a
  Actual type: Model (Sample a) a
Relevant bindings include
  x' :: Sample (Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s a)
    (bound at Test.hs:22:20)
  x :: Sample a (bound at Test.hs:22:9)
  m :: Model (Sample a) a (bound at Test.hs:22:7)
  dtest :: Model (Sample a) a -> Sample a -> Sample a
    (bound at Test.hs:22:1)
In the second argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘m’
In the first argument of ‘test’, namely ‘(fmap auto m)’
```

Edit: Got this to work with leftaroundabout's suggestion:

```
dtest :: forall a . (Num a) => (forall b . (Num b) => Model (Sample b) b) -> Sample a -> Sample a
dtest m x = grad go x
  where
    go :: forall t. (Scalar t ~ a, Mode t) => Sample t -> t
    go = test m
```

Comment: This can't work. Within `dtest`, the model is monomorphic with the rigid `a` type variable, so `ad` has no way to inject its infinitesimals (different type!) into the model. You'll need to consent yourself with some other signature like `dtest :: Num a => (∀ b . Num b => Model (Sample b) b) -> Sample a -> Sample a`.

Comment: Great, thanks! I got it work. Had to enable also RankNTypes, and modify the code a bit.

Comment: @leftroundabout: Sounds like you should post that as an answer :-)