# AD, type unification error with constrained-type Vector

Tags: haskell

I need to find the Jacobian of a `V.Vector CDouble -> V.Vector CDouble` function.

While trying to produce a minimal example from the answer  [How to do automatic differentiation on complex datatypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391114/how-to-do-automatic-differentiation-on-complex-datatypes) , I still stumble on a knot of type unification problems. The closest I got so far (complete code below) gives me the following error :

```
    Could not deduce (t ~ CDouble)
    from the context (a ~ CDouble)
      bound by the type signature for
                 jf1 :: a ~ CDouble => V.Vector a -> V.Vector (V.Vector a)
      at ADMode.hs:17:8-69
    or from (AD.Scalar t ~ a, AD.Mode t)
      bound by the type signature for
                 go :: (AD.Scalar t ~ a, AD.Mode t) => V.Vector t -> V.Vector t
      at ADMode.hs:19:9-74
      ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            go :: (AD.Scalar t ~ a, AD.Mode t) => V.Vector t -> V.Vector t
          at ADMode.hs:19:16
    Expected type: V.Vector t
      Actual type: V.Vector CDouble
```

Note: I added the instance `AD.Mode CDouble` and the constraint `(a ~ CDouble)` on the type of `jf1`; these, AFAICT, are the only relevant changes w.r.t. the referenced SO answer.

---

```
{-# language TypeFamilies, RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module ADMode where

import Foreign.C.Types

import qualified Numeric.AD as AD
import qualified Data.Vector as V

f1 :: V.Vector CDouble -> V.Vector CDouble
f1 = V.map (**2)

jf1 :: forall a. (a ~ CDouble) => V.Vector a -> V.Vector (V.Vector a)
jf1 = AD.jacobian go where
  go :: forall t. (AD.Scalar t ~ a, AD.Mode t) => V.Vector t -> V.Vector t
  go x = f1 (V.map AD.auto x)

instance AD.Mode CDouble where
  type Scalar CDouble = CDouble
  -- isKnownConstant _ = True
  -- isKnownZero x = 0 == x
  auto = id
  -- (^/) = (/)
```

I confess I still don't understand the role of the double existential quantification, and how type constraint hints (namely, `~`) interact with the type inference. On the other hand, I simply wish to make this little contraption work, for the time being ..

Any and all hints and explanations are very welcome. Thank you in advance

Comment: `AD.jacobian (fmap realToFrac . f1 . fmap realToFrac)`

Comment: Thank you @user2407038 ; it works, after diking out all the type annotations. Now I'd like to understand _why_ the type constraints simplify so much, by just applying that double pass of `realToFrac`.

Comment: The `realToFrac` just converts from `Reverse s CDouble` to `CDouble` and back. `Reverse` has an instance `(Reifies s Tape, Fractional a) => Fractional (Reverse s a)` and `(Reifies s Tape, Real a) => Real (Reverse s a)` which allows this conversion to happen. The use of `realToFrac` does not simplify the constraint - the type you have given `go` is just more general than it needs to be to begin with. You say it works for *any* `Mode t` (actually it will be `Fractional t, Real t` now) but its only instantiated with one `t` - namely `Reverse s CDouble`.

Comment: @user2407038 , do you think there's a way around this double conversion? Because on one hand it does typecheck, but on the other all the derivatives are zeroed out due to it. I suspect there's a loss of precision involved